# Angular2 modal getting errors with "no Provider for overlay"?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use this:

```
https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/blob/master/QUICKTHROUGH.md
```

I am using angular2-webpack, I npm installed angular2-modal. Following the exact instructions on the link above, I get the following error:

```
 inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Overlay!
```

Is this just me or are other people getting similar errors as well? I am using the latest version of angular through this: `https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter`

Is this some RC to final release issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in your link, you still need to import the module into your app module

```
import { ModalModule } from 'angular2-modal';
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BootstrapModalModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The module provides the overlay service to the application